Chatintents - multi intent extraction
I want to develop a tool that will take a bunch of conversation texts from call centers (between agents and users) and be able to build a multi-intent hierarchical structure based on the input data fed. I am not sure on where and how to approach this problem. If anyone can shed some light and share some samples or code references that I can further study and extend, that will be greatly helpful. After analyzing all the conversations, I must construct the intent list as below
{
"parent_intent": "Sales",
"child_intent": [
"Add Service Features",
"subchild_intent": [......],
......
.....
....
}
